# Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Identity

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm getting a, possibly misleading, error when i try to execute powershell from my c# app using powershell.

The error, as in the title, suggests that i'm missing the Identity parameter, but it isn't missing.
I tried debugging through, and confirming that the parameter is added to the Command object, before invoking.

```
var x = ps.AddScript("Remove-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy")
                    .AddParameter("Identity", "DK")
                    .AddParameter("-Force");
                x.Invoke();
```

I'm running powershell 7.2, and using System.Management.Automation.Powershell version 7.2.1.0

Any ideas as to why this happens ?

I've tried both parameters with and without the dash, making no difference.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AddParameter("Force")` (ie without the `-`) ?

Comment: It might have to, the Force parameter isn't the issue though. I tried both parameters with and without the dash, and get the same error each time, concerning the Identity parameter.

Comment: Not sure how it's done on C# but on PS you can usually create a _hashtable_ and then add it as parameters: `$hash = @{ Identity = 'DK'; Force = $true }` => `ps.AddScript(...).AddParameters($hash).Invoke()` note the _AddParameters_ vs _AddParameter_

Comment: `.AddParameter("Force", true)`

Comment: @KristianMedK - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: The change suggestions to "Force" has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was using AddScript in addition with addParameter.
When using add scripts the params should be inline in the script, if you want to use addPArameter, it should be following the AddCommand.

dashes in the parameter name in AddParameter() seems to be completely ignored.

a working example would look like this.

```
var x = ps.AddCommand"Remove-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy")
                .AddParameter("Identity", "DK")
                .AddParameter("Force");
            x.Invoke();
```